# Do Program and Shutter priority modes work on a Nikon N90s with a Series E lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, compatibility, shutter-priority, program-mode

I have a Nikon N90s camera body. Will a Series E 1.8 Nikon lens work on this body in the P and S modes? If so are there any restrictions and if so in what mode?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Nikon Camera and Lens Compatibility Chart](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-slr-camera-and-lens-compatibility) at Nikonians.org, **no**, you will not be able to use Program or Shutter-priority modes on your N90s with AI, AI-S, or E-series lenses.

Quoting a section from the chart:

> | Nikon Film SLR | ... | AI,AI-S,E |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | N90s/F90x | ... | MF<sup>1,2</sup> |
>
> **Notes**
>
> - **MF**    Manual Focus
> - **1**     Only in A (Aperture Priority) or M (Manual) modes. P (Program) or S (Shutter priority) exposure modes will not function.
> - **2**     No 3D Matrix Exposure Metering.